# Insert values into struct column?

Tags: arrays, google-cloud-platform, struct, google-bigquery, nested

I have a table in bigquery with two columns id and struct column details(record,repeated).
which has two nested fields name(string),range(string).

Tried the below query to insert the values.

```
insert into table
values(101,struct(array(['Marie','Jonas']),['High','Low']))
```

failed to load the the records. Syntax itself wrong.

I should be able to insert the values as if done by array_agg(struct()) function. My expected output is

```
id    details.name   details.range
____  ___________    _____________
101   Marie          High
      Jonas          Low
```

I would really appreciate if i get some help on this.

Comment: Hello @Amira Bedhiafi. can you help me on this question.

Comment: Hi @Saravana Kumar,I have posted an answer. I hope it will help you. Do consider upvoting and accepting if it helps, else let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Comment: Hi @kiranmathew, i am sorry, my question failed to interpret my doubt clearly.
I have made changes on the question. Please go through that one again.

Comment: Hi @Saravana kumar,I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks @kiranmathew.
That worked, Got the results as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement you can consider below query:

```
INSERT INTO my-project.my-dataset.my-table(Details) values(struct('maria' ,'high')),(struct('Jonas' ,'Low'))
```

Result:

[image]

For more information, refer to these [link1](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#insert_statement),[link2](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/nested-repeated) and [link3](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-work-with-array-and-structs-in-bigquery-9c0a2ea584a6).

**UPDATE**

Query:

```
INSERT INTO my-project.databset.table values(101,[('maria','High'),('Jonas','Low')])
```

Result:

[image]